# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. a server side problem or front end?

Tags: ajax, api

I write this code to upload audio file to server and get respose. but the problem is that it gives me this error. first the user choose an audio file and click submit. it should be sent to api address. it will be process there and then the server send back respose. is there a problem in server side?

````
   <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
   </script>

    <p>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="filechooser" />
    </p>    
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="uploadFile()" />
    </p>
  
<script>
 
        
  function uploadFile() {
    var blobFile = $('#filechooser').val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var headers = new Headers();

    formData.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

    $.ajax({
       url: "http://...../getAudio",
       type: "POST",
       headers:headers,
       mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
       data: {"file": formData},
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

       success: function(response) {
          console.log("success");
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log("error: "+errorMessage); // Optional
           console.log("error");
           //console.log(data);
       }
    });
}
</script>```
````

Comment: server side. it's supposed to include that header in the response

Comment: @mangusta it works in postman fine

Comment: sending request directly from http client is not cross-site